# Spread operator only returns the first value in Google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, debugging, spread-syntax

I'm trying to insert some values in a Google sheet using a Google Apps Script, but when I'm spreading the range that I defined earlier, it only returns the first value.

I expected `Logger.log(...pasteAndFormatRange);`, `Logger.log(pasteAndFromatRange.flat()`, and `Logger.log(pasteAndFormatRange[0], pasteAndFormatRange[1], pasteAndFormatRange[2], pasteAndFormatRange[3]);` to return `2.0, 1.0, 626.0, 9.0` , but it only returns `2.0`.

I expected `Logger.log(pasteAndFormatRange);` and `Logger.log([...pasteAndFormatRange]);` to return `[2.0, 1.0, 626.0, 9.0]`, which it does.

I have made sure that the `typeof` the array is in fact an `object`. I have tried making a new array from this array in several ways, but the new array behaves the same way.

Also this worked just fine a week ago... I guess my next step would be to define the range inside the .getRange()-method directly, but then I wouldn't be able to keep my code DRY :(

Here is the code:

```js
let pasteAndFormatRange;

  if (action === 'override') {
    pasteAndFormatRange = [2, 1, target.getLastRow()-1, target.getLastColumn()];
  }

  Logger.log(pasteAndFormatRange); // returns [2.0, 1.0, 626.0, 9.0]
  Logger.log([...pasteAndFormatRange]); // returns [2.0, 1.0, 626.0, 9.0]
  Logger.log(...pasteAndFormatRange); // returns 2.0
  Logger.log(pasteAndFormatRange[0], pasteAndFormatRange[1], pasteAndFormatRange[2], pasteAndFormatRange[3]); // returns 2.0

target.getRange(...pasteAndFormatRange).setValues(data.slice(1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Logger` doesn't support multiple arguments. Use `console.log` instead.

```
function tgi09(){
  console.log(1,2,3);//Logs 1 2 3
  Logger.log(1,2,3); //Logs 1.0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't with the spread operator.

Looking at [`Logger.log`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#log(Object))'s documentation, it takes only one argument, and thus, silently ignores the others. Keeping it as an array should do the trick, as you've seen.

Answer (score 0):

And yet if pasteFormatRange had been and array instead of a range it would have worked:

```
function myfunk() {
  const pasteAndFormatRange = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
  ];
  Logger.log([...pasteAndFormatRange]);
}

7:22:52 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:22:52 AM  Info    [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]
7:22:53 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```